# Shell script to take thread dump of a java process

Tags: java, linux, shell, java-threads

With `jstack` we can take thread dump of a running java process. With `top` and `ps -aef | grep java` commands, we can identify the rogue process using most of the system resources.

So, if we use `jstack <rogue pid> >> threaddump.log` we can take the thread dump of the specified java process.

Now my question, is there any shell script that can identify the top java process, take process id(pid), inputs to `jstack` utility and take the thread dump?

I've searched online and most of the links need manual efforts of inputting process id. So, I'm just curios to know if there is any existing shell script which can avoid manual input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this pipe works:

```
ps -eo pid,%cpu,comm | grep java |sort -nr -k2 | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs jstack
```

Explanation:

ps -eo pid,%cpu,comm : prints all processes with PID CPU usage and command name

grep java : greps all java processes

sort -nr -k2 : sorts the result numerical reverse by the second column

head -n1 : prints the first row

awk '{print $1}' : prints the first column

xargs jstack : takes the input and uses it as argument for the jstack command

Comment: Below error I'm seeing after running the above command?

ps: illegal option -- -
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u [uid,uid...]]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]

Comment: what linux distribution are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using mac... Didn't try on other linux distributions.

Comment: Try this. The options of ps seems to be different on macps -eo pid,%cpu,comm |sort -nr -k2|grep java|head -n1|awk '{print $1}'|xargs jstack

Comment: ps -eo pid,%cpu,comm |sort -nr -k2|grep java|head -n1|awk '{print $1}'|xargs jstack

Comment: Thanks this works now... Many Thanks for your answer.